# In IIS7 how can I set the number of requests IIS can handle

Tags: windows, asp.net, web-server, iis-7.5

I have a Windows 2008 / IIS 7.5 server that I want to act as a proxy for another service call.

The problem I am having is that the service I am calling often takes a while to respond, so I need the proxy to:

- not timeout
- handle as many incoming requests as it can, because it does not work other than pass the request off to the service, and wait for a response.

Can anyone offer any advice on how I can configure such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you could refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0 to configure connection and execution timeout settings for your application. It's for iis 7.0 but probably will work for 7.5 too.

For the second part of your question, you have to configure application pool settings. You can find information about how to do that in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You usually set capacity (i.e. number of threads) limits and timeout limits in your application framework (ASP, ASP.Net, etc).

If there are threading or memory scalability limiting issues, you might want to consider setting numProcesses > 1 , which creates a Web Garden; if your app requires state (or rather, is not stateless), a Web Garden isn't an appropriate choice unless you're using some form of out-of-process state.